# VSCode x SqlAlchemy integration - failing imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy

When I open my repository in VSCode, the "sqlalchemy.orm.Mapped" and "sqlalchemy.orm.mapped_column" imports are marked as invalid. The code does run, and VSCode is using the correct python environment - we're using poetry - as is evidenced by the fact that all of the other imports work correctly, and that the *other* SQLAlchemy imports seem to work as expected.

[Python version is set to the Poetry VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpkR8.png)

Because these imports are failing, any field annotated with `mapped_column` or `Mapped` is marked as `Unknown`, which is really, really annoying.

[Failing imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvoyp.png)

I've looked at the package that is being theoretically referenced by VSCode, and it does appear to have a definition for both `Mapped` and `mapped_column`. I also have attached VSCode to our dockerized build, and the same issue is happening. Finally, I've upped the depth search for pylance x sqlalchemy, but I doubt that's at all relevant.

I am really at a loss - hence this post. My only guess is that the package stubs being exported with SQLAlchemy may be out of date, but I'd have no idea about how to go and update them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

FWIW, we're using python 3.10.4 and SQLAlchemy 2.0.16

Comment: Try switching environments and reinstalling the package.